# Relative paths for assets in Play Framework

Tags: nginx, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm running two Play 2.3.x applications behind nginx. In nginx, application A is configured to be accessed at "/". Application B is configured to be accessed at "/appB/".

I'm having some problems resolving assets for application B when using the built in routes/assets functionality (`<script src="@routes.Assets.at("someScriptfile.js")") type="text/javascript"></script>`. The problem here is that the URL will be absolute, for example `/assets/file.png`. This will result in that the proxy forwards the request to application A.

I want to use relatives path instead. That would allow me to run the application B both with and without the proxy. I want the asset url to be `assets/file.png`.

What are my options? I know I can solve it by using content rewrite in the proxy, but we would

Comment: You want to just remove the leading slash?

Comment: @m-z Yes, but how do I do that when using @routes.Assets.at...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution that works.

Edit application.conf and add the following: `application.context="/appB/"`.
This will translate `<script src="@routes.Assets.at("someScriptfile.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` to url /appB/assets/someScriptfile.js

Answer (score 1):

`Assets.at` returns a `Call`, which is converted to a `String` implicitly in Scala. The `String` it produces is just the URL the reverse router resolves to. If all you want to do is remove the leading slash, you can `drop` the first character.

```
@routes.Assets.at("someScriptfile.js")").drop(1)
```

Or to be super sure that what's removed is only a leading slash, you could use `stripPrefix`.

```
@routes.Assets.at("someScriptfile.js")").stripPrefix("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
For your Application B use absolute URLs but prepend them with the "/appB/"

```java
package misc;

import controllers.routes;

public class BAssets {

    public static String at(String path) {
        return "/appB" + routes.Assets.at(path).toString();
    }
}
```

Then every time you want to serve some asset for application B, you will write it like this:

```
<script src="@misc.BAssets.at("javascripts/hello.js")"></script>
```

If you want, you can even include more logic in the method which calculates the path to the asset - for example based on if your application is in dev mode or in prod. Or even based on the proxy configuration (you can decide to change the path to appC tomorrow).

Comment: Hm, that would tie Application B with the proxy configuration.
And wouldn't the asset lookup fail when running Application B without the proxy (when developing)?

Comment: @ulejon this is what I meant by ".. you can even include more logic .." - you can, for example, remove the /appB part based on some condition - e.g. based on if your application is in dev or prod mode

Answer (score 0):

I just created a PR to have relative paths added to Play.  Looks like it will be released with 2.6.7

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/7839